# Why is Earth Engine Export.map.toCloudStorage taking much longer than before?

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I've created a script to identify the nth least cloudy mosaic for Sentinel-2 data for a given place and time. A few months ago, I was able to execute an Export.map.toCloudStorage for a visualization of Sentinel-2 data for an area a little over half as big in less than 20 minutes with the same maximum zoom. However, this export (which is a rectangle extent about 40,000 sq km) has been running for 17 hours. It appears to be working,  as I can see some map tiles in the bucket, but just taking a really long time. Have I done something in this script that would cause that or has there been a change to Earth Engine services?

The script:

```
/* This script will export the nth least cloudy Sentinel-2 mosaics for a given
region of interest (ROI), year, and range of months* as map tiles to google
cloud storage */

// Select year

var year = 2019

// Select start month

var startmonth = 3

// Select end month

var endmonth = 6

// Load the ROI table
var table = ee.FeatureCollection("users/theronmb/TTCS_Area_Extent_for_Sentinel-2");

// Find the MGRS_TILES that overlap with the ROI for the time period of interest
var collection = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2")
  .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(year,year,'year'))
  .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(startmonth,endmonth,'month'))
  .filterBounds(table)
;

//print(collection)

// Get the unique MGRS tile list
var tiles = ee.List(collection.distinct('MGRS_TILE')
  .aggregate_array('MGRS_TILE'));

var orbits = ee.List(collection.distinct('SENSING_ORBIT_NUMBER')
  .aggregate_array('SENSING_ORBIT_NUMBER'));

/* Function to iterate through the image collection to pull out the nth 
least cloudy granuales for each target tile.*/
var fun11 = function(orbit) {
  orbit = orbit;
  var fun1 = tiles.map(function(tile) {
    var S2 = collection
    .filterMetadata('SENSING_ORBIT_NUMBER', 'equals', orbit)
    .filterMetadata('MGRS_TILE', 'equals', tile)
    .sort('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', true);
    var mylist= S2.toList(3);
    var s2 = ee.Algorithms.If(ee.Number(S2.size()).gt(1), 
      ee.Image(mylist.get(0)), //change to 1 or 2 for 2nd or 3rd least cloudy
      ee.Image(0));
    return s2;
  });
  return fun1;
};

// Apply function to orbits list
var list1 = orbits.map(fun11).flatten();

// Create image collection from image list and remove blanks
var collection1 = ee.ImageCollection(list1)
    .map(function(image) {
      return image.set('count', image.bandNames().length())
    })
    .filter(ee.Filter.eq('count', 16))
    .sort('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', false);
print(collection1)

var vizParams1 = {
  bands: ['B8', 'B3', 'B2'],
  min: [640, 524, 671],
  max: [4347, 1189, 1220],
  gamma: [1, 1, 1]
};

var vizParams2 = {
  bands: ['B8', 'B3', 'B2'],
  min: [1400, 276, 157],
  max: [3910, 1624, 1183],
  gamma: [1, 1, 1]
};

Map.centerObject(table, 8);
Map.addLayer(collection1, vizParams1, 'least cloudy', 0);

// Create visualization layers.
var sent1RGB = collection1.select(['B8', 'B3', 'B2'])
  .map(function(image){return image.clip(table)})
  .mosaic()
  .visualize(vizParams1);

Map.addLayer(sent1RGB);

// Export the image to Cloud Storage.
Export.map.toCloudStorage({
  image: sent1RGB,
  description: 's2_2019_lc1',
  bucket: 'ttcs',
  maxZoom: 15,
  minZoom: 8,
  skipEmptyTiles: true,
  region: table
});
```

*****Update*****

The export completed in 18 hours. I decided to test with a much smaller area (just 2600 sq km) and the script I have used in the past to export with quick results. It has already been running for 40 minutes. It appears that something has changed with regards to the resources that Earth Engine devotes to map exports. Also, even though I specified in the export task that the map tiles objects should be public in the export, they end up being private in the bucket, where as before they were correctly set to public.

Answer (score 1):

This could happen because the changed area contains more S2 images naturally making computation take longer time as well.

Also, if you only need to export the results, than you can remove the unnecessary lines in script, such as `Map.addLayer(sent1RGB);`